# need an answer for add object in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

```
fun create(creator: Creator): Map<String, Any?> {
    return mutableMapOf(
        SearchFieldNames.WEBSITE to creator.getWebsite(),
        SearchFieldNames.WEBSITES to websiteOf(creator.getWebsites())
    )

}

private fun websiteOf(websites: List<WebSite>?): List<MutableMap<String, Any>> {
    return websites?.map {it ->
        mutableMapOf(
            SearchFieldNames.WEB_TYPE to it.webType.name,
            SearchFieldNames.URL to it.url,
        )
    }!!
}
```

i want to add websites object field in elastic search
so i made a create method for add field and add the list

but this error occurred

Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [websites] of type [keyword] in document with id '9999999998'. Preview of field's value: '{webType=ETC, url=naver.com}']

first, i made a create method for make a map
and then, i made a websiteOf method for website object to add map
but.. it occured error..

`Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [websites] of type [keyword] in document with id '9999999998'. Preview of field's value: '{webType=ETC, url=naver.com}']`

do you have a good idea?
this is the first time to use elastic search so i need your help
now i can't find the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Since the current type of `websites` is `keyword`, you can't put map to the field.

You would need to define `websites` as [object field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) in the index mappings!

```
PUT index-name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": { 
      "websites": { 
        "properties": {
          "webType":  { "type": "keyword" },
          "url":  { "type": "keyword" },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```